# How does this basic hello world statement come as an error?

Tags: java

```
class helloworld{

public static void main(String[] args){

     speaker speakerObject = new speaker(); //this becomes an error!!!
     speakerObject.greet();
}

public class speaker {
    public void greet(){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

when i try to make an object, it becomes an error!
im using VS

Comment: It looks like you have embedded `speaker` in `helloworld`; it should be in a file saved as `speaker.java` **or** make it a `public static class speaker`.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a non-static variable in a static context, and you have an error in the inner class declaration, basically it should be:

```
    public void main(String[] args){

        speaker speakerObject = new speaker();
        speakerObject.greet();
    }

    class speaker {
        public void greet(){
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an error of **No enclosing instance of type __YourClassName__ is accessible.**

Try to understand the error, speaker is an inner class of helloworld, which is by definition is associated with helloworld class. So declaring it as a static class, it won't need any instance of helloworld class.

And one more thing, If you are new to java, cultivate a habit of using first letter capital in your class name, It will be strongly appreciated if you use ***upper camel case*** for naming conventions of ***class***.

Below is the corrected code:

```
class helloworld{

public static void main(String[] args){

     speaker speakerObject = new speaker(); //this becomes an error!!!
     speakerObject.greet();
}

public static class speaker {
    public void greet(){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```